# Disabling extensions on localhost in Microsoft Edge

Tags: browser, deployment, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Simple problem really, for development purposes, I want to disable all/some extensions on localhost on Microsoft Edge.

Edge Workspaces cannot do this, and there is no obvious way to achieve this.

Went through all "native" Edge settings with no luck.

Comment: try private tab

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to test something without extension influence? If just for this purpose, you can try Liap's suggestion: running Edge in InPrivate window. Basically, extensions are not allowed in InPrivate window except you check below setting:
[image]

Or you can create a new Edge profile, the newly created one won't have extensions.

Comment: I use extensions on Private Tabs. I would have to go through turning them on/off and at that point it doesn't really offer any advantage over a normal window.

Comment: @dogsch What about creating a new Edge profile?